# Can a non-object exist in Python?

Tags: python, object, base-class

As everyone knows, everything is an object in Python. What I'm wondering about is whether it's possible to create an "object" `x` such that `isinstance(x, object)` returns `False`. I suspect it's possible with sufficient abuse of the CPython API, though achieving this with pure Python would be even more interesting.

Initially I thought that old-style classes would return `False` since the object hierarchy might not fully apply, but it seems like `isinstance(x, object)` is indeed `True` for instances of old-style classes.

While this is mostly of theoretical interest, it might be interesting (or dangerous) if Python allows the creation of a new object hierarchy disconnected from the base `object` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do everything via the C API (in particular via the awesome `forbiddenfruit` module)

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> class C: pass
... 
>>> curse(type, "__instancecheck__", lambda cls, obj: type(obj) != C)
>>> isinstance(C(), object)
False
>>> isinstance(C(), C)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, chapter 3 (Data Model): "All data in a Python program is represented by objects."  Seems clear enough.  You say the alternative "might be interesting" but there are already lots of interesting things that aren't Python.

Comment: I make a distinction between objects and `object`s. The former are OOP objects, which Python clearly uses throughout. The latter are instances of `object`, which is a specific base class in Python.